# what is the Difference between being married and being into registered civil partnership?

Tags: expressions

I found this wierd expression in Collins reading book for IELTS preparation

Comment: **being into registered civil partnership** is not an idiomatic expression.  It should read **being in a ...**   And you mean to type **weird**, not **wired**.

Comment: What did you find when you looked up those terms, and why didn’t that help you?

Comment: i fixed the typo... and for what I found confusing explanations for this term, I think legal and academic terms will always be an obstacle for a non-native speaker.

Comment: @mr.Arrow  I think to reopen this question you'll need to add more detail explaining whether you searched the web and what you found that you still find confusing.  I agree the difference between these is not obvious.

Comment: @mr.arrow : You still have a typo on **weird**.  :)

Comment: I'm not sure how there is a lack of clarity to this question when we managed to get four answers all interpreting it the same way—unless, of course, @mr.Arrow thinks that none of the answers addressed the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat complicated and requires some understanding of recent history.

Until fairly recently, homosexual couples were not allowed to legally *marry*.  "Marriage" itself is a legal term that includes various benefits (tax breaks, visitation rights, property ownership, etc.) and consequences (divorce laws, joint child custody, etc.).  However "marriage" is *also* a social and religious term, and many people, even today, are opposed to the idea that homosexuals should be allowed to "marry" each other.

Some countries, and some of the US states, proposed a compromise solution where homosexual couples could engage in "civil partnerships" (called "civil unions" in the United States) which carried the same benefits and consequences of a legal "marriage" (without using the actual word "marriage").  Under the law those who *entered into* a civil partnership were treated much the same as those who entered into a marriage.

Recent changes in the laws of many countries now allow homosexual couples to officially "marry" each other, making civil partnerships relatively moot.  Still, there are existing civil partnerships, and some couples may choose to enter into a civil partnership instead of a marriage.

More information

[Civil Partnership in the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_partnership_in_the_United_Kingdom)

[Civil Unions vs. Marriage in the United States](https://family.findlaw.com/domestic-partnerships/civil-unions-v-marriage.html)

Comment: Yes, and in France, these are called Pacs, civil solidarity pact. Also used for co-habitation when people (straight or gay) live together. They must be registered at the town hall.

Comment: thanks, Andrew, I think this legal terms will be an obstacle for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's more of a legal question than an English language question, and the answer will differ depending on the laws of any particular country.

In general a civil partnership (sometimes called a civil union) gives you the same or similar legal rights as marriage (eg. being able to inherit your spouse's wealth, or visit them in hospital), but is not recognized as marriage.

People entering civil unions usually do so either because the country does not allow them to legally marry (for example, England from 2004 to 2014 did not allow same-sex couples to marry, but allowed them to enter civil unions), or because they want to avoid the social burden of marriage while still securing the aforementioned legal rights.

Comment: I get it, I think my country has the same thing when a civilian marry a foreigner, thank you Maciej

Answer (score 0):

If you are discussing the UK a civil partnership was an interim piece of law to allow gay people to legally register their marriage, before that became legal.

I will be summarising this website for the rest of the answer
https://www.slatergordon.co.uk/media-centre/blog/2016/01/what-are-the-differences-between-marriage-and-civil-partnership/

Fundamentally there are no major differences between civil
 partnerships and marriage but there are some differences including:

- Civil partners cannot call themselves “married” for legal purposes.
- Civil partnership certificates include the names of both parents of
  the parties. Marriage certificates include the names of only the
  fathers of the parties.
- Adultery cannot be used as a reason to
  dissolve the Civil Partnership. In a marriage, if one party is
  unfaithful this is grounds for divorce. This isn’t the case in civil
  partnership dissolution. Adultery isn’t recognised in same-sex
  partners.

Comment: In the UK, a heterosexual couple is contesting the law that permits *civil partnerships* only to same sex couples, saying that it contravenes their human rights..       https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/civil-partnership-rebecca-steinfeld-charles-keidan-uk-supreme-court-couple-a8351171.html

Comment: @RonaldSole they are, but they are just point scoring

Comment: @WendyG I leave it to you and others to judge their motives

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that, in the recent past, homosexual couples were not legally allowed to marry. Instead, they had to enter into something different: a *civil partnership*.

Marriage laws have changed in some places, but not in others. (And some places don't recognize civil partnerships either.)

[Here](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-37834074) is an interesting article from the BBC that discusses the differences between the two—as well as a *heterosexual* couple who wanted to enter into a civil partnership (rather than marriage) but, ironically, were denied because they were not the same sex.

Comment: In France, they could. They should have hopped the channel. :)